# How do I setup a host that every time I push to git, files are updated on the host?

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to push to git and have my repo synced to a directory on a different host. I host my code @ GitHub and have a VPS @ Lightsail.

Is there some sort of script, cronjob, or existing framework that can be configured to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github supports [Webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) which let you set up a trigger when certain events happen in your repo. The trigger sends an HTTP POST request to a URL you configure. You can find the Webhooks section in the Settings area of your repo.

You could likely run something on your VPS that would receive that POST and then do a `git pull` on the local repo copy.